# Getting two regex matches from one command

Tags: shell

I need to parse some info out of a big nasty ps string.  I need to get the username and PID, then the /usr/user/java.instanceName/ part into one line.

I tried grep, sed and awk, but I dont know any of them that well.  And after hours of reading for this simple task, I'm hoping someone can just tap out a quick one liner.

This is the last thing I tried before asking:

```
ps auxwww | sed 's/^[a-z]* *[0-9]*//g;s/\/usr\/user\/[a-z._0-9]*//g'
```

Here is the std out from the ps auxwww command:

> root 3837  2.5 32.5 4697784 2657720 ?     Sl   Sep13  30:23
>   /usr/java/jdk16/bin                    b.WebService.port=80
>   -Dorg.jboss.naming.NamingService.port=90 -Dorg.jboss.na                    mi.port=90 -Dorg.jboss.invocation.jrmp.server.JRMPInvoker.port=40
>   -Dorg.jbos                    server.PooledInvoker.port=41 -Dorg.jboss.remoting.transport.Connector.port=42                    ing.transport.Connector.messaging.port=180
>   -Dorg.jboss.remoting.transport.Conn                    1 -Djboss.bind.address=10.0.0.1 -Dtomcat.bind.address=10.0.0.1 -Dtomca                    cat.https.port=443 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   che.cluster.name=cluster               =INVALIDATION_ASYNC
>   cache.mcast.port=457 -Dejb3.cache.mode=LOCAL
>   -Dejb3.cache.cluster.name=EJB3-en                    ss.platform.mbeanserver
>   -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.serv                    ilderImpl  -server -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiatio
>   ed.dirs=/usr/user/java.instanceName/lib/endorsed
>   -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInte                    mi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
>   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/java/jdk16/jre/                     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass123 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS                     pGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewG                    m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -jar run.jar -c jvmname -b 10.0.1.1

Comment: Maybe I'm just blind, but I don't see the sub-string "integral7" in the output from `ps` at all, so the second half of your `sed` expression is not going to do anything...

Comment: doh, I sanitized the output, I'll edit to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
ps auxww | sed -n -e '/java.instanceName/s;\(^[a-z]* *[0-9]*\).*\(/usr/user/java.instanceName[A-Za-z._0-9/]*\) .*;\1 \2;p'
```

That breaks down like this: `sed -n` turns off the default print action on every line; `/java.instanceName/` will pick only lines that have that pattern in it; the `s` command uses `;` as a delimiter because `/` is used later in the pattern; `\(^[a-z]* *[0-9]*\)` is as you had it and matches the user and PID at the beginning of the line, but with the additional effect of saving exactly what was matched; then we skip everything up until `\(/usr/user/...[A-Za-z._0-9/]*\)` which matches a path prefixed by `/usr/user/` (I tweaked the character class to include uppercase and the `/`) - that is saved for future use; finally the space after that path and everything else are matched. The `;\1 \2;p` part replaces the entire match with the two sub-parts we saved and prints it out.

Comment: That's just about right, but I forgot to mention that java.instanceName is a variable.  I need to see all instances running on a server.  I tried playing with the sed, but I dont totally understand it.  What would it take to make that variable?

Comment: Oh, so you only want the part that comes after `/usr/user/` and before `/lib...` then? In that case, `sed -n -e '/java.instanceName/s;\(^[a-z]* *[0-9]*\).*/usr/user/\([A-Za-z._0-9]*\)/lib.*;\1 \2;p'` should grab the "next part" of that string.

Comment: almost there, I keep getting a trailing /lib/endorsed which isn't a big deal, but just dropping the / from the [A-Za-z._0-9/] character class doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, got it.     ps auxww | sed -n -e '/java.instance/s;\(^[a-z0-9]* *[0-9]*\).*/usr/user/\([A-Za-z._0-9]*\)/.*;\1 \2;p'      Thank you for your help.